# Does a Levenshtein distance involve some computation for each single row?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, string, string-manipulation

Let's say I have, in a SQL DB, a table with 2 columns: `id integer, description text` and 100,000 rows. The column `description` has always < 20 characters.

If I want to:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE levenshtein_dist(description, "hello world") < 7
```

- does this require to compute the distance for each of the 100,000 rows (heavy computation!) for any implementation of [Levenshtein string similarity distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), **because this is inherent to the method**

or

- is there some clever implementation or clever technique (involving an index maybe?) that can avoid to have to loop over each single row of the table?

---

Context: I wanted to know if MySQL (or even sqlite) had an efficient mean to find string similarity. [FTS](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) (Full text search) is one but [unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35025747/1422096) (it's for sqlite here, but it might be the same for MySql?):

> SQLite's FTS engine is based on tokens - keywords that the search engine tries to match.
>   A variety of tokenizers are available, but they are relatively simple. The "simple" tokenizer simply splits up each word and lowercases it: for example, in the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", the word "jumps" would match, but not "jump". The "porter" tokenizer is a bit more advanced, stripping the conjugations of words, so that "jumps" and "jumping" would match, **but a typo like "jmups" would not.**

The latter (the fact that "jmups" cannot be found as similar to "jumps") makes it unpractical for my use case, sadly.

Comment: Your question straddles theory and rdbms-specific. Can you implement a similarity search on an index -- certainly. Do some databases implement it? Likely a few. Does MySQL or SQLite implement it -- probably not.

Comment: For MySQL, yes, the computation will be done for every row.

Answer (score 2):

## PostgreSQL

Using PostgreSQL, you can create a [trigram index on a column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) with the `pgtrgm` module and do a similarity search on it with the `<->` operator,

> `text <-> text` Returns the “distance” between the arguments, that is one minus the `similarity()` value.

note there is also `word_similarity`. I would highly suggest checking out the module, as it explicitly addresses your concerns,

> Trigram matching is a very useful tool when used in conjunction with a full text index. In particular it can help to recognize misspelled input words that will not be matched directly by the full text search mechanism.